# MSBuild error MSB3155 on Jenkins

Tags: c#, msbuild, jenkins

I am trying to build and publish a .net application through MSBuild in a Jenkins CI Server, and I am getting the errors bellow

- warning MSB3155: Item 'Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.9.2' could not be located in
- warning MSB3155: Item 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0' could not be located in

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? How could I install those components into my Bootstrapper files? (there is nothing at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper)

I am using MSBuild 4.0 (because the solution was created in vs2010) and the target framework is 2.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing a x64 version of the Microsoft Windows SDK...so the corretc path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper = Without the (x86) string.